How to hard-wire oven?
Bought a new oven for in-wall installation. New oven has black red white but junction box has 2 black 1 red 1 green 1 copper and 1 bare. I don’t know how to connect this.

Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box please, as well as the make and model of your new oven?

colors mean not much, measure voltage on each B-B, B-R, B-G

What's the difference between "1 copper" and "1 bare?"
